# Android FQL Call Returning Empty after Successful Calls [Title Changed]

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql

Ok Here's my problem.

I am making an FQL query and I am storing the response data. My code runs fine, except after about 4 minutes of the app running I get a JSONException. The Exception reads

```
   A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 0 of
```

Which is strange, because if I type in the URL the query is making into a browser I get the following

```
[{"uid":SOMENUMBER},{"uid":SOMENUMBER}]
```

Which clearly begins with the "[" character.

Here's the request

```
         String query = "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user=1 and uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 =" + fbId + ")";
         Bundle params = new Bundle();
         params.putString("method", "fql.query");
         params.putString("query", query);
         mAsyncFacebookRunner.request(null, params, new FQLRequestListener());
```

Here's the RequestListener

```
    private class FQLRequestListener implements RequestListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) 
        {
            try {
                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(response);
                friendsIds = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); ++i)
                {
                        String uid = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("uid");
                        friendsIds.add(uid);
                        Log.d("friends", friendsIds.get(i));
                }
                InviteFriends.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                            setUpList();
                    }
                });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } 
        }
```

And the Stack..

```
06-15 16:43:21.744: D/Facebook-Util(866): GET URL: THIS IS THE URL THAT WORKS IN A BROSWER (actual URL removed)
06-15 16:43:21.774: W/System.err(866): org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start    with '[' at character 0 of 
06-15 16:43:21.774: W/System.err(866):  at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:448)
06-15 16:43:21.774: W/System.err(866):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:104)
 06-15 16:43:21.774: W/System.err(866):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:150)
 06-15 16:43:21.774: W/System.err(866):     at rageup.android.InviteFriends$FQLRequestListener.onComplete(InviteFriends.java:129)
 06-15 16:43:21.774: W/System.err(866):     at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:254)
```

I should note that..

1. Query works when I logout and log back in.
2. I have ensured my Facebook session is valid.
3. The Facebook provided "Hackbook" example has the same problem when downloading a friend's list.

Flow of Getting the Exception

1. Home Page Where User Logs In
2. User Clicks a Button to Start Second Activity
3. Second Activity is Where Query is Made
4. Return Home
5. Repeat after about 4 minutes, minus the login

Comment: Unless you post your code, and more of the stack trace, it's impossible to see what's happening.

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you saying that when you start your app you login to FB and it works. Then, if you run the above code within 4 minutes it works and if you run it after 4 minutes it doesn´t?

Comment: Have you tried to use a network sniffer? Maybe that will shed some light on the problem. Also, Is the activity in the front for all those 4 minutes? What is the flow of the application?

Comment: I am not aware of what a network sniffer does. I will post the flow in the question.

Comment: A network sniffer logs all of the network traffic that is being made in the device. With that you can see the actual requests/responses. As for you flow, Is the user keeping the activity on the foreground somehow? Or maybe the activity gets paused?

Comment: I don't believe the activity is kept on the foreground. Would this even be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to validate the response.
I would use:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
```

It gives you an opportunity to check the content of the json object using it's methods. You can't assume, that facebook api will always respond expected form of data.
You can do:

```
Log.w("FacebookListener", "Unexpected response: " + response);
```

And then inspect Logcat output.

OK. I haven't tested it yet, but according to: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/ the graph path for fql queries is "fql"

In `mAsyncFacebookRunner.request(null, params, new FQLRequestListener());` you pass null, but "fql" is probably expected

**EDIT**
I have checked it on graphapi explorer - it works, when "query" is replaced by simple "q".
Make sure, you are authenticated within your app (Single sign on, or OAuth dialog)

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("q", query);
mAsyncFacebookRunner.request("fql", params, new FQLRequestListener());
```

**Another EDIT:**
While working on different project, I have noticed, that there may be a problem with Facebook Util class's method "read" - sometimes (even if InputStream had data) BufferedReader returned null, and broke loop. I have changed body of the method into:

```
 private static String read(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    final InputStreamReader rd = new InputStreamReader(in);
    try {
        final char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = rd.read(buffer)) != -1){
            sb.append(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            rd.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {

        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

and it worked.

Comment: The response is blank, any idea why this could be?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Probably passing "method" parameter to Bundle is redundant too.

Comment: Unexpected response: {"error":{"message":"Unsupported method, fql.query","type":"Exception"}}

Comment: params.putString("method", "fql.query"); - this is redundant - comment it, and check again

Comment: Ok now got this,  Unexpected response: {"error":{"message":"(#601) Parser error: unexpected end of query.","type":"OAuthException","code":601}}

Comment: Yes it does work, but the same problem as before, works for about 4 minutes and then returns no information after about 4 minutes

Comment: The response is empty (A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of ), but now if I reinitialize the activity twice it works, strange.

Comment: Remember, that Facebook object does not persist access token, and access token period. Is it good to save those values into shared preferences, and initialize Facebook object with it every time, You create new instance. The best solution which I use in my application - is to hold static global instance of Facebook.

Comment: I have a similar way of handeling the token value, expires value, and Facebook object, but the query call still follows a pattern of working for about 4 minutes, not working once, and then working for about 4 minutes. I also just checked the Hackbook example Facebook provides, it has the same error for loading the friends list.

Comment: You can use this alternative, wich requests "access_token" on every access: `code`Bundle b = new Bundle();
   b.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
   b.putString("format", "JSON");
   b.putString("query", query[0]);

   String myResult = null;
   try {

    myResult = Util.openUrl(
      "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query", "GET", b);`code`

Comment: I have worked on facebook again recently. And another discovery has been made. There is a problem in read method of Util class in facebook package. Read my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem:
calling the fql (simple fql call, not asyncfqlrunner) I have no problems at all. If I wait a few minutes (2-4) and try again sending an fql request, I get an exception by the facebook android api:

> A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of

I also have ensured that the fb session is valid und the query is correct. nothing has changed, except the time of excecution.

I tried the approche to rewrite the 
 `private static String read(InputStream in) throws IOException` method but the error still occurs.

**EDIT**
Since even facebook isn't aware of this problem and nobody else has posted anything about this I have figured it out by myself. When using the normal request-method (not the async one), go to the Facebook.java in the FB-API and change the following line under in 
the `public String request(Bundle parameters)`:

FROM:

```
return request(null, parameters, "GET");
```

TO

```
return request(null, parameters, "POST");
```

and everything should work fine!

Comment: Great find, for using the Async one, should I change the "GET"'s to "POST" 's also?

Comment: actually I didn't try it with Asyncs. I prefer implementing my own Async Tasks instead of using Facebooks. You can try it and post the result though

Comment: I tried to use this, but I stil got the same results with the Asyncs.